# PowerShell Script in PostBuild

Tags: powershell, cmd

## Continuous Integration

I have been working on a PowerShell script to keep our development process streamlined.  I was planning on running it as a post-build event, but I'm having some trouble.

From the PowerShell prompt, the following works wonderfully:

```
PS C:\> ./example.ps1
```

However, when attempting to run this from `cmd.exe` as follows:

```
C:\> powershell -command "&\"C:\path to script\example.ps1\""
```

The script executes but I get a round of errors back from PowerShell, consisting mostly of path resolution errors from the `resolve-path` function:

> Resolve-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\Documents and Settings\bdunbar\My Documents
>   \Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CgmFamilyComm\FamilyComm\iirf\cms\isapirewrite4.dl
>   l' because it does not exist.
>   At C:\Documents and Settings\bdunbar\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\C
>   gmFamilyComm\scripts\cms.ps1:4 char:27
>   +     $iirfpath = (resolve-path  <<<< ../iirf/cms/isapirewrite4.dll).path,
>
> Resolve-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\Documents and Settings\bdunbar\My Documents
>   \Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CgmFamilyComm\FamilyComm\familycomm' because it do
>   es not exist.
>   At C:\Documents and Settings\bdunbar\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\C
>   gmFamilyComm\scripts\cms.ps1:5 char:27
>   +     $vdirpath = (resolve-path  <<<< ../familycomm).path

Is there a way to work around this?  Could it be an issue with running `resolve-path` under `cmd.exe`?

## [Update]

I've been able to change things to get around the errors that are occurring, but I still receive errors that work perfectly fine from the powershell command prompt.  I can't figure out what the difference is.

Comment: What Jason said. The difference probably has to do with your resolve-path line. If in doubt, try and make your script work without using resolve-path at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've made this work in the past (see http://sharepointpdficon.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/13092#300544 if interested):

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo
>   -NonInteractive -Command .'$(ProjectDir)Deployment\PostBuildScript.ps1'
>   -ProjectDir:'$(ProjectDir)' -ConfigurationName:'$(ConfigurationName)' -TargetDir:'$(TargetDir)' -TargetFileName:'$(TargetFileName)' -TargetName:'$(TargetName)

Then throw these parameters in the first line of your post-build script (if you think you may be able to use them):

`param($ProjectDir, $ConfigurationName, $TargetDir, $TargetFileName)`

Also I should point out, I am not using this presently. I did like using it as a quick scratchpad to reload test data for running integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, this works perfectly.  What is the . for in front of the filename and how did you know to put it there?  Thanks again, +1 from me.

Comment: haha, wish I knew. I cobbled mine together from a script I found on a Channel 9 forum thread I think, now I can't find it.

Comment: I can guess that it's dot-including the script, though I didn't think you could dot-include and pass arguments into a script. Interesting.

Anyway, resolve-path would work differently if you &-executed versus dot-included the script.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. In visual studio 2017 I was able to run a Pre-build event command line script of `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -Command '$(ProjectDir)\killDotNet.ps1'`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your problem is how relative paths are resolved.  Relative paths are resolved based on the current location (stored in `$pwd`) and not based on the location of the script.  So if you launched the script from `C:\`, it definitely would not work.

I would suggest you calculate the paths based on an argument (like Peter Seale shows), or grab the actual location of the script from:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```