# Post Build Events Conditional Statement biased on text file value

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I have some post build event to minify my css and javascript using ajaxmin

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug  $(ProjectDir)..\Tools\ajaxmin.exe -xml $(ProjectDir)Scripts\Combine.xml -js -clobber
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug $(ProjectDir)..\Tools\ajaxmin.exe
```

This increased my build time from about 7 or 8 seconds to about 12 - 15, (building the project during development those seconds add up you know. I've gone to a lot of effort to reduce build time for this app. )

I'd like to run this task only if the files in the combine.xml have changed.

My initial thought is to set up a file watch windows service to write changes to a txt file,

Then check the text file on the post build command,

But I don't know how to do this last bit.

Is there a way to check a value in a Text file using post build events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a PowerShell script as postbuild event, and check the files modification dates, e.g.

```
(Get-Item .\combine.xml).LastWriteTime
```

Then you regenerate the file only if the `LastWriteTime` of the partial files is greater than the `LastWriteTime` of the combined file.

I don't know if you can do that with a regular post-build script.

Comment: some further info on [powershell for post build comands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500320/post-build-event-execute-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [FC command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490904.aspx)
This returns the differences of the two files.

```
fc file1 file2 
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0
Run your postbuild event here
```