# What is the difference in the way I launch powershell console?

Tags: powershell, module, launch, launcher, snap-in

I work with Sharepoint and I need Sharepoint snap-in present in my console host. When I run powershell from my Windows start menu, I run command

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
```

snap-in is added ok, and everything works well.

Also, everything is ok, when I run cmd.exe, and type `powershell.exe` to it and press enter. So I think no shortcut parameters are involved in this problem (but I not 100% sure :) ).

But when I launch powershell through some launcher (I've tested [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) and [Enso](http://humanized.com/enso/launcher/)) and I try to add the same snap-in, it fails with this error message:

```
Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
At somefile.ps1:7 char:14
+     Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument:(Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell:String)     
[Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

What is the difference when I launch powershell with launcher?

I think this is not sharepoint related problem but rather powershell one.

(note: I know about Sharepoint management shell and question is not about it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No sure 100% but you may have a trouble with PowerShell 32 bits versus PowerShell 64 Bits.

For Example if your SnapIn is 64 bits, it can be only use with PowerShell 64 bits. If *Launchy* and *Enso* are 32 bits they starts powerShell 32 bits that look for a 32 bits SnapIn. It's the same thing in the other side.

**From a 64 bits process**, you can force using PowerShell 64 bits using :

```
c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**From a 64 bits process**, you can force using PowerShell 32 bits using :

```
c:\windows\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**From a 32 bits process**, you can force using PowerShell 64 bits using (Read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589/en-us)):

```
c:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Comment: Ok, that IS the difference. Thank you.
I have both choices when I type `powershell` - Windows Powershell and Windows Powershell (x86). But powershell is started as 32 bit no matter what version I am trying to run. (Enso is 32bit I guess.)
Is this normal behavior? Is there some way to launch 64 bit powershell from 32 bit launcher?