# start a process in "BUILD EVENTS" in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone knows how to start a process in "build events" visual studio?
for example

```
TASKKILL /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /F
sleep 3
if $(ConfigurationName)==Debug @echo do some stuff of building and copyng dll files build 
C:\notepad.exe
```

in the last line, it get stuck and it can't finish to build dll.
I try to add ampersand like linux shell to run the process but i didn't have any success.

Answer (score 2):

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

This "start" command looks promising.

Comment: "start" command line doesn't work. the entire post build events get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your post build event to finish while the application started is still running, you can use [cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/):

```
C:\Tools\cmdow.exe /Run C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

Where `C:\Tools\` is the path where you extracted the executable to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running your build event in an external script file.*

For example, add this to Post-build event:

```sh
powershell.exe -file "$(ProjectDir)Build\Post-build.ps1" -ConfigurationName "$(ConfigurationName)" -PlatformName "$(PlatformName)" -TargetDir "$(TargetDir)"
```

and create this file under project directory:

**Build\Post-build.ps1**

```
param(
    [string]$ConfigurationName,
    [string]$PlatformName,
    [string]$TargetDir
)

#[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
#[void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("It works.")

Get-Process Notepad | kill
Start-Sleep -seconds 1
if ($ConfigurationName -eq 'Debug')
{
    # Run some debug configuration tasks
}

Start-Process C:\notepad.exe
```

<sub>* Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501719/450913) answer with some modification.</sub>