# Compiling all LESS files in the solution into a single file

Tags: visual-studio, less

I have lots of .less files in my solution, one per page.

I want to add a build step that quickly runs through my solution and puts all the files ending in .less into one massive .less file.

I've not found anything that specifically does this via google. I don't want to compile to CSS, at least not at this point.

Is there a tool out there that will do this? Or should I write one myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can [run a powershell script in a  postbuildevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500320/post-build-event-execute-powershell):

```
ls d:\temp\ -r -i *.less| gc | sc -enc UTF8 d:\temp\allless.less
```

- `d:\temp\` is your root solution folder
- `d:\temp\allless.less` the resulting file

Comment: xD powershell is very cool. it is a shame to have waited so long compared to Linux users